# Using Postfix+Dovecot+MySQL, enable a catch-all+forward for a domain, while still allowing authenticated outgoing access

Tags: postfix, dovecot, debian-squeeze

I have a server with Debian 6 (Squeeze), running Postfix, Dovecot, and using MySQL as the backing store for virtual email accounts.

For my domain `example.com`, I have a ‘catch-all’ `@example.com` that forwards to `myaccount@gmail.com`.

I want to allow an authenticated user to log in as `me@example.com` to use SMTP (and thus take advantage of SPF validation and DKIM signing), but not allow Postfix to deliver mail sent to `me@example.com` to Dovecot. Configuring a ‘full’ account in the MySQL database causes this to happen, so far as I can tell.

How can I do this? Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix is intelligent enough to not deliver mail to Dovecot if you are forwarding mail for that address.

In practice, this means a minimum of four records are required in the MySQL database:

`domains`: `example.com`
`forwardings`: `@example.com` `->` `me@example.com`
`forwardings`: `me@example.com` `->` `myaccount@gmail.com`
`users`: `me@example.com`, `somepassword`

With this configuration, Postfix will deliver all mail to `example.com` to `myaccount@gmail.com`, but still allow `me@example.com` to log in via SMTP and send outgoing mail, enabling that mail to, e.g. be signed for DKIM.